# How to concatenate a variable into an array string on VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, excel, concatenation

I'd like to use a variable inside an array like this

```
path = "C:\test\folder\"

Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=path;")
```

but am unable to concatenate the variable into this array correctly.

Do you have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add strings with the `&` operator directly into commands such as:

```
Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & path & ";")
```

Comment: thx @enderland - i tried that but I get Run Time error 1004 (Application defined or object defined error)

Comment: Are you sure that works with your filepath? Try directly copying your filepath into the test you are running instead of `=path`.